# Open a new NeoVim window using Windows terminal

Tags: windows, windows-terminal, neovim

I am currently using NeoVim by running it from the Windows terminal (Windows 10), using the nvim command. For the moment, if I type Neovim in the Windows search bar and open the app, it opens in the default ugly black window.

Is there a way to tell Neovim to always open inside the Windows terminal instead of typing the nvim command from there each time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make create a desktop icon that will call up Neovim inside
the Windows Terminal.

If I understood correctly how you're calling up Neovim, create
a desktop icon that contains this command:

```
wt nvim
```

This will start up the Windows Terminal and execute the command `nvim`. In case of an error, use the full path to `nvim`.

For more information see
[Using command line arguments for Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows).

Comment: That works, thank you !